# How to update dict within alot of other dicts without changing the dicts around that dict in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

How to update dict within alot of other dicts without changing the dicts around that dict in pymongo

Im using flask with this aswell, which is why there is `request.form.get()` in this and why the code below has indent, i just got rid of the stuff that wasnt relevant.

```py
      if request.form.get("name") and request.form.get("link"):
        db.update_one(
          {
            "name":request.cookies.get("x-session-name")
          },
          {
            "$set":{
              "settings":{
                "profile": {
                  "links":{
                    request.form.get("name"):request.form.get("link")
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        )
```

What I want:

```json
"_id": {"$oid": "644c642274116376d944b39"},
"name": "John_Doe",
"password": "$2b$12$Iggpw3gd94oifZg1YqQiVeWalpRjtKbG3/MoYPVxRefceye2cRJfm",
"email": "$2b$12$G5YMsfVnMAeMlcKuUnQBWOai8S8XQx710AECLVZ0rY.wJOlrtxkBG",
"settings": {
  "dob": {
    "year": 1990,
    "month": 11,
    "day": 10
  },
  "profile": {
      "bio": "My bio",
      "status": "status",
      "expiry": "N",
      "badges": [
        "beta",
        "staff",
        "verified"
      ],
      "links": {
        "my cool site": "https://example.net/coolstuff",
        "my cooler site": "https://example.com/coolerstuff"
      }
      "picture": {
        "active": true,
        "meta": "base64 nonesense"
      }
```

What I get:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "644c642274116376d944b39"
  },
  "name": "John_Doe",
  "password": "$2b$12$Iggpw3gd94oifZg1YqQiVeWalpRjtKbG3/MoYPVxRefceye2cRJfm",
  "email": "$2b$12$G5YMsfVnMAeMlcKuUnQBWOai8S8XQx710AECLVZ0rY.wJOlrtxkBG",
  "settings": {
    "profile": {
      "links": {
        "my cooler site": "https://example.com/coolerstuff"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ive tried $push aswell, but it just created an array which doesnt help me here.

Comment: For simplicity of future queries, you might want to model `"links"` as something like `"links": [{"label": "my cool site", "url": "https://example.net/coolstuff"},{"label": "my cooler site", "url": "https://example.com/coolerstuff"}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a pipeline in the update, it seems to work as you want.

```js
db.update_one({
  "name":request.cookies.get("x-session-name")
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "settings": {
        "profile": {
          "links": {
            request.form.get("name"): request.form.get("link")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ANrMu9YC0Y).

Comment: TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'update' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Comment: @2vw  It was a carryover from mongoplayground.net.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Using @rickhg12hs' response i managed to come up with a solution using the brackets

```py
db.update_one(
  {
    "name": request.cookies.get("x-session-name")
  },
        [
          {
            "$set": {
              "settings": {
                "profile": {
                  "links": {
                    request.form.get("name"): request.form.get("link")
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ])
```